# Is "type" and "status" a reserved word in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I can't find these in words in the MySQL manual for reserved words but apparently phpMyAdmin says they're reserved:

[image]

Comment: Really, there is no reference to these words in the manual. But because they are words that carry a "meaning" there are restrictions on its use.

I have created tables with these, if this does not prevent him to manipulate them simply ignore.

Comment: @PiLHA: The point is that reserved words *cannot* be used as unquoted SQL identifiers; whereas these words *can*.  phpMyAdmin is incorrect to state that these words are reserved.

Comment: @eggyal As far as I know, both in SQLServer as it happens in MySQL. The maximum restriction for the use of the terms is to add '' or [] and solve. Bug or not, use.

Comment: I noticed that now, in phpMyAdmin 4.0.5, this issue has been resolved. And words like `type` and `status` do not show messages anymore. Also, reserved keywords that "MySQL permits to be used as unquoted identifiers", such as `date` and `timestamp`, no longer have a notification either, though they once did. (I suppose it could have gone either way with those)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is, technically, a bug in phpMyAdmin.  From [`libraries/sqlparser.data.php`](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/libraries/sqlparser.data.php#L677):

```php
/**
 * words forbidden to be used as column or table name wihtout quotes
 * as seen in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/reserved-words.html
 *
 * @global array MySQL forbidden words
 */
$PMA_SQPdata_forbidden_word = array (
```

(list includes `'STATUS'` and `'TYPE'`, which are clearly not on the referenced manual page).

[Bug #948](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/948/) identified that phpMyAdmin at that time capitalised certain column names (including `STATUS`) due to (erroneously) being identified as reserved words from this list; those keywords were initially [removed](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/1940971c6ee5f3ee6189673a888e54325d6ec59d) from the list as a result, but that commit was subsequently [reversed](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/f67172c0230b659ec1ee40b1e79c199600431ecc), for [the reasons explained by Alexander Turek](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/948/#ef26):

> Your fix messes up the pretty-printer!
>   This is rather an analyzer problem.
>
> FIRST and STATUS have been inside this reserved words array 
>   because they are part of MySQL commands.
>   STATUS is used in "SHOW STATUS" and FIRST part of the 
>   ALTER sytax.
>
> Furthermore, this bug affects a lot more words than just 
>   STATUS and FIRST. I do not want to know what happens if we 
>   remove them all from the reserved words array...
>
> Because of your change, both queries are not highlighted well 
>   anymore.

That is to say, phpMyAdmin uses the same list of words to conduct syntax highlighting in its pretty printer as it does for detecting reserved words; this is erroneous and leads to the warnings you observe.