# SQL query: Query browser shows error 1064

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-error-1064

I cant find what happened to the MYSQL query. It was working fine and today it is throwing 1064 error can anyone help me.

In query browser i am getting 1064 error

and in mysqli_error i am getting "Unknown column 's.firstname' in 'field list'".

query ::

```
SELECT s.recid userId, s.firstname firstName, s.lastname lastName, s.email email, s.status status
FROM usertable s
WHERE s.email = 'xyz@gmail.com'
AND s.mobile = 'XXXXXXXX'
AND (s.enddate IS NULL OR s.enddate = '0000-00-00' OR s.enddate > '2015-04-08 11:13:34')
```

Error :

Unknown column 's.firstname' in 'field list'

Comment: Is it possible that your field is actually called 'firstName' with a capital 'N'?

Comment: The table `usertable` does not (any longer?) have a field called `firstname`.

Comment: check your column name from your database.

Comment: Please run query SELECT * FROM usertable LIMIT1. And post the result here WITH column names.

Answer (score 0):

Check the firstname spelling, white spaces on start and end of the field, if its okay, then remove firstname from query and then try it once.
This will help us to debug.

Comment: Yes.. all the columns are there.... their spelling and text casing is also correct still i am getting this issue..

Comment: can you send dump for that particular table

Answer (score 0):

Check your table has the column `firstname`

Use below command to check it within query browser

```
DESC usertable;
```

Comment: Yes.. all the columns are there.... their spelling and text casing is also correct still i am getting this issue..

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap everything with backticks (or at least column name called status) and see what happens...

```
SELECT `s`.`recid` `userId`, `s`.`firstname` `firstName`, `s`.`lastname` `lastName`, `s`.`email` `email`, `s`.`status` `status`
FROM `usertable` `s`
WHERE `s`.`email` = 'xyz@gmail.com'
AND `s`.`mobile` = 'XXXXXXXX'
AND (`s`.`enddate` IS NULL OR `s`.`enddate` = '0000-00-00' OR `s`.`enddate` > '2015-04-08 11:13:34')
```

Note that you are using status as column name, but even if it isn't declared as keyword it is used in queries like SHOW STATUS...So I will avoid that and change its name to something else. Also using status like this in some versions of phpMyAdmin produced some [unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16593413/3402095). But when you wrap it with backticks  you can use it as column name.